# How to add a key-up event on textbox to catch user's "enter" input

Tags: google-apps-script

My condition is that I have a textbox and a button, when user input something in the textbox and hit enter, I would like to go for the same handler as that button's. 
I see there's function in textbox called addKeyUpHandler, but the function seems only works like the example below.

```
  // Create handler to mark the input in textBoxB as valid
  var onInvalidInput1 = app.createClientHandler()
      .validateNumber(textBoxB)
      .forTargets(textBoxB).setStyleAttribute("color", "black");

  // Add all the handlers to be called when the user types in the text boxes
  textBoxA.addKeyUpHandler(onInvalidInput1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with ClientHandlers. You certainly can with ServerHandlers. There's more than one way to skin a cat but this works, so have a play with something like this. Here I'm using two different ServerHandlers, one for the TextBox and one for the Button and piping them them through to a common doAction function. You could of course use a single handler for them both, but that adds the overhead of every keyUp event being sent to the server, even before you know it's a valid number.

```
// Script-as-app template.
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  var textbox = app.createTextBox().setName('textbox');
  app.add(textbox);
  var button = app.createButton('Click Me');
  app.add(button);
  var label = app.createLabel('___').setId('lbl');
  app.add(label);

  // only fire ServerHandler for onKeyUp if it passees validation
  var textBoxHandler = app.createServerHandler('textBoxHandlerFunction').validateNumber(textbox);
  var buttonHandler = app.createServerHandler('buttonHandlerFunction');
  textBoxHandler.addCallbackElement(textbox);
  buttonHandler.addCallbackElement(textbox);

  textbox.addKeyUpHandler(textBoxHandler);
  button.addClickHandler(buttonHandler);

  return app;
}

function textBoxHandlerFunction(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  if(e.parameter.keyCode == 13)
  {
    app = doAction(app, e);
  }
  return app;
}

function buttonHandlerFunction(e) {
  // missing validation that textbox is a number
  return doAction(UiApp.getActiveApplication(), e);
}

function doAction(app, e)
{
  // do your stuff
  app.getElementById('lbl').setText('fired...' + e.parameter.textbox);
  return app;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used createServerHandler and updated my code below.

Answer (score 0):

I finally used the code below.

```
function doGet() { 
  var tb_search = myapp.createTextBox().setName('tb_search').setId('tb_search').setWidth(LENGTH_MIDDLE)
  var btn_search = myapp.createButton('Go').setId('btn_search');  

  var h_search = myapp.createServerClickHandler('procSearch');
  h_search.addCallbackElement(tb_search);  
  btn_search.addClickHandler(h_search);      

  var h_tb_keyup = myapp.createServerHandler('procSearch') 
  tb_search.addKeyUpHandler(h_tb_keyup)
}


function procSearch(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication(); 
  // return if the key is not enter.     
  if((e.parameter.eventType=="keyup") && (e.parameter.keyCode != 13))
  {
    return app;
  }
}
```